# SpriteKit physics body fail to detect contact for thin object

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am making space shooter game with Sprite Kit.
One problem I face is that it sometimes fail to detect collision between two objects if one of it moves too fast or it is too thin.

One possible solution I found is setting "usesPreciseCollisionDetection" property to YES, but it is not working well as expected.

How can I guarantee to detect collision between two physics bodies?

Thank you

Comment: For starters you should post the relevant code to your issue.

Comment: usesPreciseCollisionDetection: what does "not working well" mean? No change? Does it work better but they still pass through? Have you set that property on all potentially fast-moving, dynamic bodies?

Comment: Hi LearnCocos2D, Yes I set usesPreciseCollisionDetection both on fast moving object(bullet)and thin object(wall). But the bullet still pass through the wall.